# Regular expression check for email ID fails

Tags: c#, regex, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, email-validation

I got this regex check for Email ID from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.110).aspx). But it fails when _ and @ comes one after the other.

**Expression:**

```
 @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
                @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$",
```

Example: check_@hotmail.com fails even though it is a valid ID.

Where do I need to alter the string, it looks really messy and I do not understand it.

Comment: As there is a formal specification for email addresses , does anyone know of a formally approved regex that is exactly the specification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `(?<=[0-9a-z])@` in your regex  to `(?<=[0-9a-z_])@`

`(?<=[0-9a-z])@` asserts that the match `@` must be preceded by `0-9` or `a-z`.

So by adding `_` inside the char class would also allow `_` to be present before `@`.

Assertion only not enough, we have to add real chars (ie, the pattern which actually matches the underscore symbol). Don't worry, `\w` inside the char class which exists before `lookbehind + @` will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i am using :

```
mRegex = new Regex(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-])([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*)@(\[((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}|((([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,}|(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\])$");
```

It works fine

Answer (score 0):

It is because of this thing in your regex

```
    (?<=[0-9a-z])@
```

requires explicitly a letter or a digit before the "@".

It is better to use Microsoft EmailAddress Validation attribute to validate email address rather than Regex. Or use this function to validate email address on server side.

```
    public bool IsValid(string emailaddress)
      {
       try
    {
        MailAddress m = new MailAddress(emailaddress);

        return true;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see MailAdress. Think the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations is not yet available to Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Is it now valid for Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this : "\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*.\w+([-.]\w+)*". I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are right it is not yet available in windows Phone 8.
You can use something like below to validate email:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public static bool IsValidEmail(string strIn)
{
   // Return true if strIn is in valid e-mail format.
      return Regex.IsMatch(strIn, 
      @"^[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*"
      + "@"
      + @"((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))$"); 
}
```